# How can I match this patern over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Given the below text, I want to return an array of all the the lines of text with the following format `1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1.1` and this should macth a line even if it is actually broken across multiple lines

**RegExp:**
`str.match(/\d{1,2}.SSRDOCSYYHK1\/\/\/\/\/.+?\d\.\d/g)`

**Full Text:**

```
var str= "A-CA25592185
A-ERNONREF/CHGFEEPLUSFAREDIF/CXL BY FLT TIME NOVALUE
TKG FAX-NOT PRICED  FARE TYPE EX 
FOP- 1.CA 
G- 1.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////25MAY55/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN -  1.    
1 
)>MD
    2.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/M-  1.1 
    3.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////25AUG52/F//YOUNG/LILY/LIMKUO -  2.1 
    4.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/F-  2.1 
    5.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////25AUG52/F//YOUNG/ANDREA/LAUREN -  3.1 
    6.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/F-  3.1 
    7.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////17MAR93/M//YOUNG/ETHAN/WESLEY -  4.1 
    8.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/M-  4.1 
    9.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////23NOV96/M//YOUNG/WINSTON/JEREMY -  5.1 
   10.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/M-  5.1 
   11.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25MAY55/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN -  1.   
1 
   12.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////04MAR59/F//YOUNG/LILY/LIMKUO -  2.1 
   13.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/F//YOUNG/ANDREA/LAUREN -  3.1 
)>MD
    7.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/ETHAN/WESLEY -  4.1 
    8.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/M-  4.1 
    9.SSRDOCSWSHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/WINSTON/JEREMY -  5.1 
   10.SSRPSPTYYHK1///25AUG52/M-  5.1 
   11.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25MAY55/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN -  1.   
1 
   12.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/F//YOUNG/LILY/LIMKUO -  2.1 
   13.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/F//YOUNG/ANDREA/LAUREN -  3.1 
   14.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/ETHAN/WESLEY -  4.1 
   15.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/WINSTON/JEREMY -  5.1 
**** ITEMS SUPPRESSED ****/DR"
```

I expect an array with all the matches but the two instances of line 11 are not matched due to the line break which  can occur in any of the below way and will not currently be matched:

```
var str="1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//
YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1.1"

var str="1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1.
1"

var str="1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1
.1"

var str="1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 
1.1"

var str="1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN
- 1.1"
```

How change I tell this RegExp to still match in all of the above cases?

I did try `str.match(/\d{1,2}.SSRDOCSYYHK1\/\/\/\/\/.+?\d\.\d/m)` with no luck

Heres the array that I do get:

[image]

---

anubhava's answer below returns the following array, note that slots 0 and 2 actually hold two lines that were captured as a single instance. This always happens when a line breaks like this and is followed by another matching line if I use his example.

[image]

Comment: What did you use `.match()` on? You're not giving a lot of information here.

Comment: Im not sure I follow. I gave 6 examples of the the text im using this on. ...I guess I can edit it to be more clear

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean by _next lines_. Edit: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Should I have said new lines? Or would some other discription be more clear? (no sarcasm, serious question)

Comment: I guess, they basically mean the same. I was just missing the point of what you actually want to do (and it's still nog 100% clear to me). Could you give an example of the text input, and the output you want?

Comment: Ok edited, that should give you a much clear picture, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be broken anywhere, not only in the `DOT` matching, the `\s` trick won't work.
I don't think there's a way to ignore line breaks in javascript regex (or any other engine, actually).

Your best option would be to remove all line breaks before matching, like so:

```
str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

And then you `.match`

Comment: Oddly when I do this I get an array with only one slot filled with the following string "11.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25MAY55/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN - 1. 1 12.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////04MAR59/F//YOUNG/LILY/LIMKUO - 2.1"

Comment: I've changed the regex you used in the fiddle (missing global flag and added whitespace ignorer). See if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/MtZc4/

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe you posted the wrong link. That appears to be the original fiddle

Comment: Gotcha, that's definately the right track. Is there a reliable way to get rid of any spaces left between the "1."  and the "1". I tried just `.replace(".   ","."` but thats not very versatile considering that there could be more or fewer spaces left there.   see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/MtZc4/3/

Comment: Wow, so by doing `'$1.$2'` I assume you are basically using match[1] and match[2], Is that right? If so thats awesome. i had no idea one could do that.

Comment: Yep. Each parens in the regex create a group, and the `$n` reference a group in that order

Answer (score 1):

Ok. below `regular` work for `1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1.1`

```
[0-1]\.[A-Z]+[0-1]\/\/\/\/\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\/[A-Z]\/\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\-\s[0-1]\.[0-1]
```

And it work for :

```
1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1.
1

[0-1]\.[A-Z]+[0-1]\/\/\/\/\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\/[A-Z]\/\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\-\s[0-1]\.\n[0-1]
```

And it work for :

```
1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 1
.1

[0-1]\.[A-Z]+[0-1]\/\/\/\/\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\/[A-Z]\/\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\-\s[0-1]\n\.[0-1]
```

And it work for :

```
1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN- 
1.1

[0-1]\.[A-Z]+[0-1]\/\/\/\/\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\/[A-Z]\/\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\-\n[0-1]\.[0-1]
```

And it work for :

```
1.SSRDOCSYYHK1/////25AUG52/M//YOUNG/LANDON/KWAN
- 1.1
[0-1]\.[A-Z]+[0-1]\/\/\/\/\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+\/[A-Z]\/\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+\n\-\s[0-1]\.[0-1]
```

now you should define nested if and else .....(Conditional statements)

good look.

Comment: Hmm, this doesnt seem to match on any of the examples you gave using that website or RegEx buddy to test. Also this would potentially match lines starting with "5.SSRDOCSWSHK1": which would not be desirable

Comment: All of work for me in javaScript and for 5.SSRDOCSWSHK1 . you can [0-9] or [0-5] instead [0-1] .

Answer (score 0):

DOT in Javascript doesn't match new lines and unfortunately there is no DOTALL switch in JS regex engine.

**However as a workaround you can use `[\s\S]` for DOT and match regex across new lines as well.**

Following regex should work for you:

```
var arr = str.match(/\d{1,2}\.SSRDOCSYYHK1\/{3,5}[\s\S]+?\d\.\d/g);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/QIYCMA

Comment: This does work, however in my larger text this will match match two consecutive lines as one instance if the first line breaks like the above. I made my question more clear

Comment: `str.match(/\d{1,2}\.SSRDOCSYYHK1\/{3,5}[\s\S]+?\d\.\d/g)` is still giving me all the matches shown in your image.

Comment: see edit above, that new picture may be clearer than I could explain